# wordpress post with two subtitles

Tags: php, wordpress, subtitle

I want to add tu subtitles to my wordpress blogs. Cause I didn't get it work with custom meta fields is used this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-subtitle/

This actualy does work if  I use it only once.

I made a copy of this plugin and renamed all id's/classes/functions etc. but there is one information which is the same in both and i dont know how to change it.

```
function the_company_meta_save($post_id){

    //check to see if this is an autosafe and if the nonce is verified:
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    if (!isset($_POST['the_company_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['the_company_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    //update the postmeta accordingly:
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'the_company_subtitle', $_POST['subtitle']);
    return;
}
```

This is the same in both plugins and this is the reason why it doesnt work correctly:

```
$_POST['subtitle']);
```

If I change 'subtitle' of one plugin it still does not work, but i have to change it because if I dont, both subtitles show the same information. But they should show different ones.

Comment: not a direct answer but this will make your life a lot easier.. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: @reikyoushin 10/10. Would recommend again.

Comment: uuuh - this looks really good - i'll try it :D thank ya